# Finding multiple docs using same id not working, using meteor + react and mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How do I get the email address of the students in the same class_id, take it as there are more then 2 students in different class in the DB as well?

I have this but it return empty array []

```
Meteor.users.find({"course_learn_list.$.class_id": {$in: [classId]}}, 
            {field: {"emails.address": 1}}
        ).fetch()
```

Collections

```
{
      "_id": "LMZiLKs2MRhZiiwoS",
      "course_learn_list": [
        {
          "course_id": "M8EiKfxAAzy25WmFH",
          "class_id": "jePhNgEuXLM3ZCt98"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "5hbwrfbfxAAzy2nrg",
          "class_id": "dfbfnEuXLM3fngndn"
        }
      ],
      "emails": [
        {
          "address": "student1@gmail.com",
          "verified": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "JgfdLKs2MRhZJgfNgk",
      "course_learn_list": [
        {
          "course_id": "M8EiKfxAAzy25WmFH",
          "class_id": "jePhNgEuXLM3ZCt98"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "5hbwrfbfxAAzy2nrg",
          "class_id": "dfbfnEuXLM3fngndn"
        }
      ],
      "emails": [
        {
          "address": "student2@gmail.com",
          "verified": false
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
Meteor.users.find({ "course_learn_list.class_id": classId }, 
    { "course_learn_list.$": 1, "emails.address": 1 }).fetch()
```

This should find the first instance in each course_learn_list array where the classId is your classId.

Comment: hmm are you actually publishing all meteor users?

Comment: oh yes need to publish it, i put them in meteor.method

Answer (score 0):

In this case you probably don't need to use a projection to get the right answer. Here's an example of extracting the verified email addresses using only the `.` operator in the selector:

```js
const ids = ['jePhNgEuXLM3ZCt98', 'some-other-id'];
const emails =
  Meteor.users.find({ 'course_learn_list.class_id': { $in: ids } })
  .fetch()
  .map(user => _.findWhere(user.emails, { verified: true }).address);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!

```
Meteor.publish("getMyClassStudents", function(classId) {
    console.log("Publish getMyClassStudents")
    var self = this
    if (self.userId) {
        var  data = Meteor.users.find({
            "course_learn_list.class_id": classId
        }, {
            "fields": {
                "emails.address": 1
            }
        })
        return data
    }
    else {
        return self.ready()
    }
})
```